# Button's background color turns grey when mouse hovering on it C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I made a simple design for my WinForms app in Photoshop and I want to make some borderless buttons. In FlatAppearance properties, I changed border size to 0 and the FlatSyle is Flat but when the mouse is hovering on the button, its background color turns to grey, although I changed it to transparent. I'll attach some pics to get the problem better.

Can somebody help me, please?

How I want to look:

[image: how I want to look]

how it looks

[image: how it looks]

Comment: If you could share your code as a fully functional example, it would help out.

Comment: I think it is a problem with the button's properties, not with the code.

Comment: The only code on that is to enter to another screen, it is used as a play button.

Comment: If you really think the button is the problem, you could replace it with a PictureBox and then handle the Click event of that

Comment: amm...that worked :))
THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same place that you changed the border size to zero, change the `MouseOverBackColor` to `Transparent`:

[image]